# Trying to extract a list from AD that contains all of my users, in exception to one OU named Disabled Users. How can I exclude this OU from my list?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

This is what I have so far:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Department -like "*"' -Properties * |
    Select -Property DisplayName,GivenName,Surname,Title,Department,Office,OfficePhone |
    Export-CSV "C:\ad-users.csv"
```

Comment: I was able to incorporate this part from @Santiago Squarzon to refine the code But when I try to run the -LDAPFilter the query produces an empty spreadsheet.

$properties = @(
    'DisplayName'
    'GivenName'
    'Surname'
    'Title'
    'Department'
    'Office'
    'OfficePhone'
    'UserPrincipalName' 
)
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Department -like "*"' -Properties $properties |
    Select-Object $properties |
    Export-Csv "C:\ad-users.csv"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Where-Object` clause to filter on the users OU

```
# fill in the DistinguishedName of the 'Disabled Users' OU here
$ouToExclude = 'OU=...'

# Get-ADUser by default returns these properties:
# DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName
# so you only need to ask for extra properties not already in this list
Get-ADUser -Filter "Department -like '*'" -Properties DisplayName,Title,Department,Office,OfficePhone |
Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*$ouToExclude" } | 
Select-Object DisplayName,GivenName,Surname,Title,Department,Office,OfficePhone |  
Export-Csv "C:\ad-users.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: thank you! your solution worked in excluding the Disabled Users OU from the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could do it this way using `-LDAPFilter`, first you need to query the OU to Exclude and get it's `DistinguishedName` then you can query all users and filter them where their `DistinguishedName` does not contain the OU to exclude.

**NOTE:** This assumes there is **only 1** OU with Name **Disabled Users**. If there are more OUs with the same I would recommend you to *hardcode* the `DistinguishedName` of the excluded OU in `$ouDN`.

It's also worth noting that querying **all attributes** (`-Properties *`) for **all users** is highly inefficient, you should always query only the attributes of interest (`-Properties attrib1, attrib2, etc`).

```
$properties = @(
    'DisplayName'
    'GivenName'
    'Surname'
    'Title'
    'Department'
    'Office'
    'OfficePhone'
)
$ouToExclude = 'Disabled Users'
$ouDN = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter "(Name=$ouToExclude)").DistinguishedName
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(Department=*)" -Properties $properties | & {
    process {
        if($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*$ouDN") { $_ }
    }
} | Select-Object $properties | Export-Csv "C:\ad-users.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Unfortunately, AD doesn't allow the use of wildcards when querying DN attributes. You'll have to remove them from the list after the results are returned.

Comment: Thank you @GabrielLuci getting rusty with AD :(

Comment: This solution did not fix the problem.

Comment: @BrianFigueroa not fix the problem is not very informative, maybe you can explain why

Comment: My bad, I replied in the wrong section...
I was able to incorporate this part from @Santiago Squarzon to refine the code But when I try to run the -LDAPFilter the query produces an empty spreadsheet. 

$properties = @(
    'DisplayName'
    'GivenName'
    'Surname'
    'Title'
    'Department'
    'Office'
    'OfficePhone'
    'UserPrincipalName' 
)
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Department -like "*"' -Properties $properties |
    Select-Object $properties |
    Export-Csv "C:\ad-users.csv"